# Is there a way to rejig a dataframe to show a better time series dataset?

Tags: pandas, dataframe

Hi I have the following df:

```
        Variable  Total   Month

            Year
            2011    110      01
            2011    111      02
            2011    112      03
            2011    113      04
            2011    114      05
            2011    115      06
            ....
            ....
            2021    302      04
            2021    303      05
            2021    304      06
```

Is it possible to rejig the dataset to this:

```
                    Jan  Feb  Mar  Apr  May .... Nov Dec

            Year
            2011    110  111  112  113  114
            2012    ...
            2013    ...
            2014    ...
            2015    ...
            ....
            2020
            2021
```

** I would also like to remove the "Variable" word at the corner of the table.

My eventual goal is to do some simple data visualization using matplotlib to create line plots of the respective years (2011...2021)

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `pivot()`+`reindex()`:

```
from calendar import month_abbr

df['Month']=pd.to_datetime(df['Month'],format='%m').dt.strftime('%b')
df=df.pivot(columns='Month',values='Total').rename_axis(columns=None)
df=df.reindex(columns=month_abbr[1:])
```

OR

via `pivot()`+`pd.Categorical()`:

```
df['Month']=pd.to_datetime(df['Month'],format='%m').dt.strftime('%b')
df=df.pivot(columns='Month',values='Total').rename_axis(columns=None)
df.columns=pd.Categorical(df.columns,month_abbr[1:],ordered=True)
df=df.sort_index(axis=1)
```

Now if you print `df` you will get your expected output

Comment: Thank you so much!! It works perfectly! I hope to be as good as you one day. I am practicing and learning everyday to be better